# Is the partial sum of cosine bounded?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Is it true that $\sum_{k=1}^n \cos k$ is a bounded sequence? If so how to prove? I want to prove the series of $\cos n/(\sqrt n)$ is convergent by abel test but I dont know if the partial sums of cosine are bounded

thanks

Comment: I don't recognise "partial sums are bounded" as being a condition for Abel's test, but you may wish to consider the complex sequence $e^{in}/\sqrt{n}$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint**. Assume $x \in (0,2\pi)$ with $e^{ix}\neq 1$. One may write
$$
\left|\sum_{k=1}^n\cos kx\right|=\left|\Re \sum_{k=1}^{n} (e^{ix})^k \right|=\left|\Re\: \frac{e^{ix}(1-e^{inx})}{1-e^{ix}}\right|\le \frac2{|1-e^{ix}|}.
$$ Putting $x:=1$ gives a bound for the given sum.

Answer (score 4):

If you just write $$\cos(k) = \frac12 (e^{ik} + e^{-ik})$$  it will reduce the problem to the summation of two geometric sums. So, $$S_n=\sum_{k=1}^n \cos(k)= \frac12\left(\frac{e^i \left(-1+e^{i n}\right)}{-1+e^i}+\frac{e^{-i n} \left(-1+e^{i n}\right)}{-1+e^i} \right)$$ $$S_n=\frac{1}{2} \left(\cos (n)+\cot \left(\frac{1}{2}\right) \sin (n)-1\right)=\frac{1}{2} \left(\csc \left(\frac{1}{2}\right) \sin
   \left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)-1\right)$$

Comment: or just write real part of $e^{ik}$ and do what Olivier did :)

Comment: @madmatician. I totally agree. It was just another approach.

Comment: @madmatician Isn't it such a wonderous thing that we can take the real part through the sum?