# Convergence of $ \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{\cos(k\theta)}{k^p}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

> For what values of $\theta$ and $p$ is the series $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{\cos(k\theta)}{k^p}$ (i) convergent and (ii) divergent?

It's easy to prove that for $p > 1$ and $\theta \in \mathbb{R}$, the series is convergent. How do I solve for the remaining values of of $\theta$ and $p$ ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For $\theta\in\mathbb R$:

By the Dirichlet test, [knowing that $\left|\sum_{k=1}^N\cos(k\theta)\right|$ is bounded](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1860118/is-the-partial-sum-of-cosine-bounded) for $\theta\ne2\pi n$ and that $\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac1{k^p}=0$ is sufficient to show the sum converges, thus we have $\Re(p)>0$.

For $\theta=2\pi n$, your sum simplifies down to $\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{k^p}$, which converges only for $\Re(p)>1$ by the integral test.

For $\Re(p)\le0$, see that $\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{\cos(k\theta)}{k^p}$ does not pass the term test.

---

And, lastly if you really wish to consider $\theta\notin\mathbb R$, see that it will not pass the term test and will diverge exponentially.

Comment: Didn't know Dirichlet test. Anyways, got it. Thanks :)

Comment: @shauryagupta Too many tests to possibly know huh?  :D

Comment: @achillehui True, my bad.